# Get the method that threw the exception?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

How do we get the method that threw the exception in Javascript?

For example:

```
function method()
try { throw new Error('oh oh')}
catch(e) { e.stack... how to get the method ...}
```

Tried:

```
      console.log("The method is: " + e.method);
```

But it comes up as `undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.stack` property will contain a string showing the stack trace - the first line will be the error thrown, the second line will list the containing function name (if any) and line / column number that threw the error:

```js
function method() {
  try {
    throw new Error('oh oh')
  } catch (e) {
    console.dir(e.stack.split('\n')[1]);
  }
}
method();
```

Answer (score 1):

This library might suit your needs : http://www.eriwen.com/javascript/stacktrace-update/